# PivotItem in VBA reports an Item that does not exist

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code, which prints a PivotTable by changing the PivotFilter (as below).

My problem is that, after printing the last PivotItem (pivF=27), the "pivI.Name" changes to "999", which doesn't exist in my worksheet and in the PivotTable. So the macro reports an error message "Runtime Error 5".

Interestingly, the same code in another worksheet in the same file works properly without error!

Can anyone help me please?

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim pivF As PivotField
Dim pivI As PivotItem

Set pivF = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tourenplan").PivotFields("Tour")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each pivI In pivF.PivotItems
    pivF.CurrentPage = pivI.Name
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
Next pivI

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

With so thanks,
Dio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem yesterday...

check in the `Pivot Table options` (right click on the table), in `Data tab`, you should find `Retain items deleted from the data source`, choose `None` for `Number of items to retain per field`, then refresh.

If it doesn't works, change the settings (all the settings on the `Data tab`), save, close, open again, check again the same options and set `Number of items to retain per field` to `None`.

Comment: You're welcome.
Yup... Thank you @R3uK for your original answer.

Comment: There's 45 minutes I'm not getting back... what a stupid thing to enable by default.

Comment: @DaveCullum: I'm at like two days before finding this! Time to see if I can disable it with VBA